# Tree Traversal: From Leaf to leaf and then up to the root

Tags: c++, tree, traversal, tree-traversal

Even though I am programming for quite some time I have to admit that I am struggling to come up with an algorithm that traverses a tree from leaf to leaf and then up, like this (the direction in which the inner nodes are traversed doesn't actually matter, `4` and `5` can be switched if necessary):

[image]

My setup at the moment looks like this (this is not a necessary a binary tree even though my drawing might suggest that):

```
struct Node {
    void *data;
    std::vector<Node*> next;
    std::vector<Node*> prev;
};

struct Tree {
    Node *root;
    
    TreeIterator begin() {
        
        /* Start at the very left leaf */
        Node *left_leaf = root;
        
        while( !left_leaf->next.empty() ) {
            left_leaf = left_leaf->next.first();
        }
        
        return TreeIterator(left_leaf);
    }
    
    TreeIterator end() { return TreeIterator(root); }
};

struct TreeIterator {
    
    TreeIterator(Node *_node) : node(_node) { }
    
    Node* operator*() const { return node; }
    void* operator->() const { return node->data; }
    
    TreeIterator& operator++() const {
        /* TODO: Jump to the next leaf and / or upwards */
        return *this;
    }
    
private:
    Node *node;
};
```

Do you might consider to give me some hints?

Comment: Looks like [topological sort](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Topological_sorting). Note that the graph in your picture is not in fact a tree (in a tree, every node has at most one parent).

Comment: That isn't a tree. And how do you intend to step from one leaf to another without passing through some non-leaf nodes?

Comment: @Beta Thank's a lot for your reply. This is basically how the iterator over the graph would traverse.

Answer (score 3, accepted):

1. Make a BFS
2. Each node you take out of the `queue` you push_back into a `vector`.
3. Traverse the vector in reverse order.

Basically something like this:

```
queue<Node> q;
vector<Node> answer;
q.push(root);
while(!q.empty())
{
    Node first = q.front();
    answer.push_back(first);
    q.pop();
    for(every NODE reachable from first)
        q.push(NODE);
}
reverse(begin(answer), end(answer));
```

This is just the algorithm, I've put the closest to code that I could. You can make your iterator logic using vector `answer` now.

You could use a stack instead. The main point is: by traversing in a BFS you are doing the reverse sequence of what you are trying to achieve.

Comment: I do agree with your point but you need to create a new object (vector 'answer') that can be used for traversing. In other words, it is not a true iteration from the tree itself without duplicating all the information of the tree in another temporary structure. I am currently facing similar issues to properly write a tree leaves iterator without duplicating nodes.